# Fullscreen navigation drawer

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, drawerlayout

I have a navigation drawer like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o3uTO.png).

What I want to do is open my drawer to fullscreen not half screen.
How do I make this drawer to open as full screen?

This is xml of drawerlayout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<include
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
    layout="@layout/app_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/toolbar_layout"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/activityMainContent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:itemTextColor="@android:color/white"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can try this **`navigationView`** property 100% work

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:layout_marginEnd="-65dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="-65dp"
    app:itemTextColor="@color/lightgray"
    app:itemIconTint="@color/colorAccent"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />
```

Answer (score 2):

try this hope it works:

```
<include
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        layout="@layout/drawer"
        android:layout_marginLeft="-64dp"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to put your `DrawerLayout` as a main layout in your `xml` like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/toolbar_layout"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<include
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
    layout="@layout/app_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/activityMainContent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:itemTextColor="@android:color/white"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: Doing this will take my toolbar inside drawer i.e it will not be on top as in picture which is not my requirement. I want toolbar to stay on top above drawerlayout and open side drawer to full screen instead of half screen.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can achieve it.

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:layout_marginEnd="-65dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="-65dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
      />
```

Answer (score 0):

In the main Drawerlayout class there is variable as
`private static final int MIN_DRAWER_MARGIN = 64;`

So to make full drawer just give `android:layout_marginStart="-64dp"` to navigation view or the container where the drawer will be loaded.

Answer (score -2):

Try changing  `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` to  `android:layout_width="fill_parent"`

and this should fix your issue, and let me know......

Comment: tried this solution, but it still not covering whole screen. Some portion is still left out.

Comment: fill_parent is deprecated.