# send drawer content behind main content for reveal effect

Tags: android, view, navigation-drawer, drawerlayout

Using android `DrawerLayout` I'm trying to create a reveal effect. i.e.
The main content when dragged reveals the drawer content behind it.

Using ActionBarToggle for moving main content  with drawer instead overlay but the drawer content is above main content viewrather being behind it.

> How can I make the drawer content appear behind main content?

`mainContent.bringToFront()` won't work

**I want to design [something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X5PZL.jpg)**

My code for moving drawer :

```
  ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, 0, 0) {

            @Override
            public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset) {
                super.onDrawerSlide(drawerView, slideOffset);
                if (drawerView.getId() == R.id.right_drawer) slideOffset *= -1;



                drawerView.setTranslationX(drawerView.getWidth() * (1 - slideOffset));
                mainContent.bringToFront(); //not working

                mainContent.setTranslationX(drawerView.getWidth() * slideOffset);

            }
        };

        drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);
```

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/44045273/7666442

Comment: I don't want a fullscreen drawer.How that can help me? I've added my code,please review the question